# Mark mapped pages as discardable when the don't come from the paging-file

Tags: winapi

As I understand VirtualAlloc, it allows to mark mapped pages of the **paging-file** as discardable. But I want to make pages mapped to a **file** which is read-only as discardable. What do I have to do with whe WinAPI for that ?

Comment: what you mean under *discardable* ? `MEM_RESET` ?

Comment: Of course I mean MEM_RESET.

Comment: Can you share the specific scenario of your question, are you using `CreateFileMapping`?

Comment: are you use `PAGE_WRITECOPY` protection and modify pages in memory and want mark this pages as not modified ?

Comment: I've got a large set of read-only mapped pages and I want to incrementally mark pages of that set as eligible to be discarded. What I indirectly want is that fresh pages become available in the system for other mapped pages of my mapping. The result should be that if I have a mapping that's larger than my RAM, scanning that mapping shouldn't kick important pages out of the memory.

Comment: @BonitaMontero - look like you not understand what is do `MEM_RESET` - *If the pages are in memory and modified, they are marked as not modified*. if you use read-only pages - it not modified anyway. not need `MEM_RESET` at all in your case

Comment: That's not what the documentation says. The documentation says that MEM_RESET marks the page that it is no longer of interested, i.e. it can be discarded.

Comment: Do you want the function like [`OfferVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-offervirtualmemory) or [`DiscardVirtualMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-discardvirtualmemory?redirectedfrom=MSDN)?

Comment: Interesting API, Drake Wu, but I didn't get it working with file-mappings.

Comment: Could you share the minimal sample that you create the file-mappings?